# How to add package description to Nuget packed with DotNetCoreCLI

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I have the following Azure DevOps task which creates a `nuget pack` before it´s pushed to the artifact.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Pack'
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      nobuild: false
      packDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(directory)'
```

How can I add a package description for the nuget pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `buildProperties: '$description$=mydescription'` to the task:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Pack'
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      nobuild: false
      packDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(directory)'
      buildProperties: 'description=test'
```

[What is `buildProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#arguments)?

> Specifies a list of `token = value` pairs, separated by semicolons,
> where each occurrence of $token$ in the .nuspec file will be replaced
> with the given value. Values can be strings in quotation marks

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove the dollar signs like this 'description=test' possibly because I am using the on premise version of a Azure Devops.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use nuspec file:

This is csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NuspecFile>package.nuspec</NuspecFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

this is nuspec files

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <!-- Required elements-->
        <id>UniqeName</id>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <description>UniqueName</description>
        <authors>Krzysztof Madej</authors>

        <!-- Optional elements -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\netstandard2.0\*" target="lib" />
    </files>
</package>
```

And this is a build

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet pack"
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:PackageID=my_id -p:PackageVersion=2.1.0
    packagesToPack: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/stackoverflow/08-nuget-packager/SampleApp.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```