# Azure DevOps Artifacts feed does not contain a package description

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, artifacts

I am using an Azure DevOps to publish a nuget package in private Artifacts feed.
The pipeline contains these last tasks:

```
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main')
    displayName: 'dotnet pack'
    inputs:
      command: pack
      packagesToPack: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/xxx/xxxx.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
      versioningScheme: byEnvVar
      versionEnvVar: PackageVersion

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main')
    displayName: 'dotnet push'
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

in Artifacts I would like to specifiy a Package **description** in the created nuget. However it is always "default". I tried with AssemblyInfo.cs and .nuspec file but none helped.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solevd adding the following in the .csproj:

```
<Description>my desc</Description>
```

Comment: The description pulls from the `<Description>` in the project file or the `$description` in the [.nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec). In addition to directly defining it in the `.csproj` file, you can also define it in the `.nuspec` file. At the same time, you can also replace the `<Description>` in the `.nuspec` file through the parameter `buildProperties` in the DotNetCoreCLI task. See the samples from this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64315881/how-to-add-package-description-to-nuget-packed-with-dotnetcorecli).

Comment: Hey @toto' do you put the Description inside the <PropertyGroup> tag? I'm doing that, the package is created ok, inside the package the ".nuspec" have the correct description, but then, on devops it always say "Description: description" and nothing more

Comment: well I did not want to add a .nuspec file so I've solved as described above. tks